# How to set semi-transparent image to Shell background?

Tags: java, swt, transparent

I am developping an SWT application, and  I want to give the application a background png,but setBackgroundImage is not support transparent. Is there any way to solve the problem? There are some semi-transparent pixels , I wish to see desktop on these positions.
ps  the shell is no-trim style

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking around on the net? I found this, think it should help you

http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet180.java

You can also refer here for some more examples which can help you later on

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/